# How to create a website to display pairs of images and ask the users for input?

Tags: javascript, html, image, webserver, server

I want to create a very simple webpage to display pairs of images at a time and ask for user input about them (a simple question). I will have a database where the pairs of images are stored and the results should also be saved.

I have very small previous knowledge of HTML programming and no javascript programming. Can someone please give me some insight on how to start since I have currently no idea of the steps I need to perform in order to create this webpage.

I appreciate any help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any need of javascript for this requirement but you need a server side language like java (jsp) or PHP to make connection with the database.

You need a database also, like MySQL or mongodb etc.

Depending upon the server side language you have to get a server to put your program.

For user input you can use below html command.

```html
<input type="text" name="userinput">
```